# javadoc auto generation for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Is there an automatic Javadoc generation plugin for IntelliJ? Example http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Javadoc as html or Javadoc as embedded (/** doc */) in code?

Answer (score 7):

Javadoc *generation* (writing the .html files) is done for you on-demand (Tools->Generate Javadoc) and is essentially automatic once you set it up. Generating javadoc *stubs*, which is what jautodoc for Eclipse does, is done method-by-method, class-by-class and only where you tell it to.

Typing `/** <enter>` above a method signature will create Javadoc stubs for you. I suspect you want something that will do this for an entire file, package or project though (like jautodoc). There used to be such a plugin: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=952 but it won't work with 10.

I do have to say that this jautodoc example, while a neat party trick, is the single most useless thing I've ever seen in an IDE: It creates a description based on the variable name - but only if the variable name is so descriptive that it doesn't need a comment in the first place.

```
/**
 * The number of questions
 */
private int numberOfQuestions;
```

Makes you yearn for punched card.

Comment: Some build systems use checkstyle, jalopy etc. They end up requiring people to add the lame javadocs. Best practice is to make your code speak for itself but when you are stuck creating data bloat because of your corporate policy that requires it then jautodoc like functions are nice to have. ctrl alt j and you are good to commit.

Comment: Agreed @branchgabriel, IntelliJ should have something like JAutodoc, missing it badly!

Answer (score 4):

Updated the answer for `2020.3` version of IntelliJ (also works in `2019.2`)

1. **Download** plugin "***JavaDoc***" (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A` > `Plugins` > `Marketplace` tab > search for `JavaDoc` (by vendor: "Sergey Timofiychuk") > Install)

and follow below steps (from Step 2).

--PREVIOUS ANSWER--

Tested below in `2018.2` version of IntelliJ

1. **Download** plugin "JavaDoc2" (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A` > `Plugins` > `Browse Repositories...` > `JavaDoc2`)
2. **Restart** IntelliJ (`File` > `Invalid Caches/Restart...` > `Just Restart`)
3. **For current element:** To generate Javadoc for current element (say a setter method), press `Alt` + `Shift` + `G`.  If this doesn't work due to different keymap association, try `Alt` + `Insert` and selecting `Create JavaDocs for the selected element`
4. **Whole class:** To generate for the whole class, press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `G` (or `Alt` + `Insert` and selecting `Create JavaDocs for all elements`)

(One caveat is, it is generating javadoc only for public methods, not for fields and private methods)

Comment: seems to be dead for 2020.3 -- at least it's not in the marketplace plugins

Comment: @elonderin Updated the answer for 2020.3